# what does "all he likes "mean in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I'm quite puzzled by  "all he likes" in the following sentences. What does it mean ?

> But were the protests to start to spread from the far east, Mr Putin would face a similar calculus. He can arrest and intimidate the elites all he likes. [source](https://www.economist.com/leaders/2020/08/29/russians-and-belarusians-are-tired-of-backwards-looking-autocrats)

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "All he likes" is synonymous to "to his heart's content". In other words, Putin is doing whatever he wants.

The phrase can also be used to express that a person's actions are futile, such as "Complain all you like, but the answer is no."

Comment: thanks. my another question is what role is "all you like "playing in the sentence"complain all you like". Is it a attributive clause?

Comment: I'm 95% sure it isn't. Attributive clauses are also known as relative clauses. Relative clauses always start with relative pronouns like "who". If anything, "all you like" is an adverb clause.

Comment: Yes, and the idiomatic usage is this: to [action verb] all [pronoun] like or likes. She can sing all she likes. They can cheat all they like. We can play tennis all we like.